# Когда задаю margin - top тексту в css вместе с текстом двигается и фон. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить

Tags: html, css

```css
.the_main_inf {
  background-color: #f26522;
  height: 858px;
}

.inf {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 236px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="the_main_inf">
    <div class="inf">
      <p align="center">Sell Your House Instantly</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эм... А почему нельзя использовать padding? Думаю, что в этом случае, это более чем уместно:

```
padding-top: 236px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в схлопывании margin'ов.

Одно из возможных исправлений - добавить `overflow: hidden` контейнеру:

```css
.the_main_inf {
  background-color: #f26522;
  height: 858px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inf {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 236px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="the_main_inf">
    <div class="inf">
      <p align="center">Sell Your House Instantly</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```